# Let the user decide how many items in a page

Tags: reactjs, computation

**Context**

We have a table with 155 elements,

I want to build this field on every pages,

> 'Showing result [from starting item - to item number X ] of itemTotal'
>   [image]

StartingItem = 1 -----> at page 1

ItemNumberX = the user can see the next 25 items

this is the actual pages filter

[image]

These are data that I actually have

```
  const minShowData = currentPage === 1 ? 1 : (currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage;
  const itemsAtCurrentPage = currentPage * itemsPerPage;
  const maxShowData =
    totalCount > itemsAtCurrentPage ? itemsAtCurrentPage : totalCount;
  const showElement = [5, 10, 20, 25, 50]; ----> this is the old pagination
```

we have the data `itemsPerPage` through a reducer, and represent how many items we will see in page, in the second field `risultati per pagina` is set to `2`.

this is how the variable `showElement` appear

[image]

there is a way with these data to made a filter like

`Showing results [1-25, 26-50, 51-75 ...] of 155` ?

I don't need the code to build the component, just understand if there is a way to build the computation inside the field

Comment: So you get the step count from the user or are you pre-defining step count?
If you have show 20-30 items, you use a for loop of totalitems/numberOfItems, so 101/20 = 5, so the first one is (1-1)*(20)+1 and 1*(20), second is (2-1)*(20)+1 and 2*20, etc.
Just be sure to do a modulous check at the end after your for loop, so 101%20 = 1, there will be one extra page with that final left-over item.

Comment: Just to be clear: 
1st Case) i've 155 items, the user will see 25 items per page everytime and he can choose the index of items to see. Ex: 1-25, 26-50, 51-75 etc. 
2nd Case) I-ve 30 items, the items can see item 1-25, 26-30.

it's a predefining step count i think. 
The user can only see the items in a range of 25.

Comment: So this is a case of echoing the correct output to say what page you're on in terms of items?

Comment: Yes, it's this case. 
Ex) i'f i want to see the items 26-50 ( if they exists ofc) i will be in the second page and I need to show 26-50 in the field. If i will click on 51-75 i will be in the third page and i need to show 51-75 in the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you have

`const itemsPerPage = 25; //this you can set to be user alterable if you want
const itemsTotal = 155; //this you'd use a function to go get the number of items.`

const pageIncrements[];

for (let pageNumber = 1; pageNumber <= itemsTotal / itemsPerPage; pageNumber++) {
   pageIncrements += [((pageNumber - 1) * (itemsPerPage) + 1)) + " - " + (pageNumber * itemsPerPage)]
}
if (itemsTotal % itemsPerPage > 0) {
    pageIncrements += [(itemsTotal - (itemsTotal % itemsPerPage)) + " - " + itemsTotal]
}

Sorry, haven't worked with react syntax, but the logic should be right.